# How to create nested JSON format table from flat table in BigQuery?

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have a wide flat table, stored in Google bigquery in the folowing similar format :

> log_date:integer,sessionid:integer,computer:string,ip:string,event_id:integer,amount:float

I'm trying to create this table in hierarchical nested format  , having 2 nested levels  , as following :

```
 [
  {
    "name": "log_date",
    "type": "integer"
  }, 
  {
    "name": "session",
    "type": "record",
    "mode": "repeated",
    "fields": [                 
     {
       "name": "sessionid",
       "type": "integer"
         },
     {
       "name": "computer",
       "type": "string"
        },
        {
       "name": "ip",
       "type": "string"
        },
        {
    "name": "event",
    "type": "record",
    "mode": "repeated",
    "fields": [
    {
       "name": "event_id",
       "type": "integer"
     },
     {
       "name": "amount",
       "type": "float"
     }]] } ]
```

What is the best way to generate the json formatted data file from bigquery table ?
Is there a different and faster approach than 
1. download the table into external csv
2. build the json record , and write it into external file 
3. upload the external json file into new bigquery table

Can we have a direct process that generates json from existing tables ?

Thank you , H

Answer (score 1):

There isn't currently a way to automatically transform the data to a nested format. If you'd like to get the data out in json format rather than CSV, you can use the export commend with the `--destination_format` flag set to `NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON`.
e.g.

```
bq extract \
    --destination_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON \
    yourdataset.table \
    gs://your_bucket/result*.json
```

Comment: Thanks , But i guess that extracting in JSON format will not support the nested record that i'm trying to build , any other solutions regarding how to generate hierarchical table , based on flat table in bq ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with [`array_agg`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#array_agg) in standard SQL.

Note that if you want to nest in layers there need to be common table expressions as an `array_agg` can not directly contain another `array_agg`.

```
WITH DATA AS (
 SELECT 1 AS log_date, 10 AS sessionid, 'a' AS computer, '1.2.3.4' AS ip, 100 AS event_id, 1 AS amount
 UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS log_date, 11 AS sessionid, 'b' AS computer, '1.2.3.5' AS ip, 101 AS event_id, 2 AS amount
 UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS log_date, 11 AS sessionid, 'b' AS computer, '1.2.3.5' AS ip, 102 AS event_id, 3 AS amount
 UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS log_date, 20 AS sessionid, 'a' AS computer, '1.2.3.4' AS ip, 200 AS event_id, 4 AS amount
 UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS log_date, 20 AS sessionid, 'a' AS computer, '1.2.3.4' AS ip, 201 AS event_id, 5 AS amount
 UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS log_date, 21 AS sessionid, 'c' AS computer, '1.2.3.6' AS ip, 202 AS event_id, 6 AS amount ),
inner_Aggregate AS (
  SELECT
    log_date,
    sessionid,
    computer,
    ip,
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(event_id, amount)) AS event
  FROM
    DATA
  GROUP BY
    log_date,
    sessionid,
    computer,
    ip )
SELECT
  log_date,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(sessionid, computer, ip, event )) AS session
FROM
  inner_Aggregate
GROUP BY
  log_date
```